# CSS shadowbox height is not covering inner <div>s

Tags: html, css

My `<div>` shadow box height is not covering inner `<div>`s height.

[image]

```
 mainPageContent {
    padding: 5px 5px 25px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
 }
```

### generated html

```
<div class="mainPageContent">
     <div>
         <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" id="box_front_top"> <!-- bootstrap grid columns -->
          ----
          ----
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1" id="box_front_bottom" style="display: none;">
          ---
          ----
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Have a demo you can give us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your inner divs are floated , then they do not affect the containers height unless you use the clear fix trick..

Try adding `overflow:hidden` on the container

```
 .mainPageContent {
    padding: 5px 5px 25px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;

    overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try pull mainPageContent to the top of the stack using position relative + z-index?

Something like:

```
 .mainPageContent {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 999;
 padding: 5px 5px 25px 5px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc; }
```

I'm not sure if it will work in this case because you need the shadow to be above it's children, but could be worth a shot.